# installing *.CLS (e.g., ASL.CLS) with MikTex on windows 7 pro

Tags: miktex, installing

when I try to compile

```
\documentclass[bibother]{asl}
\begin{document}
foo bar baz
\end{document}
```

I get the error: "**file 'asl.cls' not found**".
According to some postings it seems that *asl.cls* must be installed via running initexmf utility, e.g.,

> initexmf --admin --update-fndb

but did not help me. I got the following error:
**'Option --admin requires admin privileges'**
and if I do

> initexmf --update-fndb

there are no errors, but I still can't compile tex code (same latex error).

Any suggestions?

Comment: No, visit the [Association for Symbolic Logic Typesetting Group website](http://www.math.ucla.edu/~asl/), download [`asl.cls`](http://www.math.ucla.edu/~asl/asl.cls) and [place it in a location where TeX can find it](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1137/5764).

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: @Werner No what? You seem to be answering 'Any suggestions?' negatively but then give what seems like an excellent one ;).

Comment: @cfr: Oh, I didn't even read the "any suggestions" part... I just read "according to some postings it seems like `asl.cls` must be installed via running `initexmf` utility...", to which my response was "No". :-| Let's see what Paul says...

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) You don't have to sign with your name since [it automatically appears in the lower right corner](http://tex.stackexchange.com/faq#signatures) of your post.

Answer (score 0):

with the help received from this cite, I was able to solve the problem.

1. Place '*.cls' in one of the folders where other *.cls files are located. E.g., I put 'asl.cls' to 'C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\amscls'
2. Run MikTeX 2.9 -> Maintenance (Admin) -> Package Manager (Admin)

That's it!
Thank you all who helped.
Paul

Comment: It looks like you've got two separate accounts, which means you cannot edit your original post or leave comments. The StackExchange staff can [merge them together for you](http://tex.stackexchange.com/help/user-merge).